# como consumo una api?

Tags: javascript, html

estoy aprendiendo a manejar angular, y necesito consumir una api de pokemon en el codigo js escribi esto:

```
const url = 'https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/1/'

fetch(url)

.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {

    let element = document.getElementById('elem')
    element.innerHTML = '<p>${data.name}</p>'
        
    console.log(data)
})
.catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

y en html escribi esto:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id ='elem'>
        <script src="conexion.js"></script> 
       
    </div>
  
</body>
</html>
```

pero cuando corro el html no me devuelve el valor del nombre del pokemon

Comment: Hola! Leiste la documentacion de la api, si necesita autenticacion o algo? porque intente copiar la url en el firefox y me pedia un captcha. Tal vez falta algo de autorizacion.

Comment: Fijate en **inspeccionar elemento** > pestaña **red** o **network** que dice cuando se ejecuta la llamada a la api. Para ver si realmente se esta llamando o si no lo hace. Ademas puede que te este dando algun error en esa llamada o por medio de la consola, fijate si puedes revisar eso.

Comment: ya lo solucione solo era cambiar las comillas por esto ``

Comment: Considera poner tu solución como respuesta, después puedes marcarla aceptada para que otros sepan qué hacer en una situación como la tuya. Describe qué cambiaste y pon código de ejemplo :)